# Which dealloc method is called first?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

Let's say I have a 2 classes, classes A and B. By composition, Class A has an instance of Class B. In other words, Class A is the one creating the instance of Class B.

If I'm in the final release of my object which is a kind of class A, will the dealloc method of Class B be executed first? Is this always the case? Will there be a case where the dealloc of Class A will be executed before Class B?

I'm trying to understand the order in which the dealloc method of classes will be executed.

(This is in ARC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete (or, in real terms, remove the last strong reference to) the instance of class A, it will be deallocated. Under ARC, as *part of its deallocation*, it will remove its strong reference to the instance of class B, which will then be deallocated if nothing else has a strong reference to it.

So, A's dealloc method is called first.

If you're depending on this order of operations to *do* anything, that is a pretty bad code smell.

Comment: And the gory details are here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#dealloc. In particular: "The instance variables for an ARC-compiled class will be destroyed at some point after control enters the dealloc method for the root class of the class."

Comment: oh. so A will be called first but B will be deallocated before A. how about the code inside the dealloc functions? Since A's dealloc method is called first, does this mean the code inside the dealloc of A will be executed before B's? 

Oh. I just want to deeply understand dealloc. thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: *"B will be deallocated before A's dealloc method completes"* is perhaps slightly misleading. B will be deallocated before the deallocation of A completes. But if both A and B provide a `dealloc` method, A's method will be called first. At least that is how I understand: "A class may provide a method definition for an instance method named dealloc. This method will be called after the final release of the object but before it is deallocated or any of its instance variables are destroyed".

Comment: So, A's dealloc code will be executed before B's. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: okay. sorry for asking so many questions. One last one, though; let's say A also owns C. So A creates B and C. Then A is destroyed. which among B and C will be destroyed first? If B and C both implement dealloc, which dealloc will be executed first? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot delete an Objective-C instance. You can only send it a release message (respectively ARC will do that). To be honest, this answer could have been much clearer, it's still confusing and misleading. @MartinR got it right.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I used the term "Delete" because the questioner used that term, I thought it would help him understand the answer. Feel free to write a better one yourself.

Comment: @user1681701 there is no order that can be determined. And you really shouldn't care about it.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper i got what he meant by delete = no more retain count (final release).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper i also updated my question to avoid confusion. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @user1681701 It is probably easier to understand if you view it that way: "retainable" objects only have a `release` or `retain` API. The dealloc method gets called as a _side effect_ of sending `release` to an object, if and only if it's retain count decreases to zero. The dealloc method itself only sends `release` to the ivars. And the process repeats.

Answer (score 1):

When the last strong reference to a given object goes away, its `-dealloc` will run, and it will remove all of its strong references to its instance variables. If those were the last strong references to *those* objects, then the process will repeat for them.

In other words, if A owns B, then A will be deallocated before B.

Comment: _remove_? You certainly meant _release_ ;)

Comment: I intentionally used the more abstract word to focus on the semantics of the operation "getting rid of the reference" rather than the mechanism "decrementing the refcount"